# How to find effective rate of interest?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance, applications, actuarial-science

A man charges at the rate of $10$ paise per rupee per month, payable in advance. What effective rate of interest does he charges per annum?

Here rate is $10\%$ per month. So to change it in per annum, I divided it by $12$ and set $n$ to $1$.

$$\text{effective rate}=\left(1+ \frac{r}{100}\right)^n -1$$

After applying the formula, I got

$$\left(1+ \frac {10}{1200}\right) -1$$

But I am getting the wrong answer and the correct answer is $254.5\%$. Please help me understand this.

Comment: One Rupee = 100 paisa

Comment: Feel free to [mark one of the answers as accepted](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the check mark (✓) icon next to the answer on the left. Doing so will mark the question as answered, and will also award both you and the author of the answer a few reputation points. Also note that users that [accept good answers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) are also more likely to have their future questions answered.

Answer (score 4):

Since the man charges interest at the rate of $10$ paise per rupee per month, payable in advance, this implies that $10$ paise can be treated as interest on $90$ paise.

For example, if you borrow $100$ paise and pay $10\%$ interest in advance, then you have only borrowed $90$ paise. Therefore the monthly interest rate $j$ is calculated as follows
$$j=\frac{10}{100-10}=\frac{10}{90}=\frac19$$
Since we already know the monthly interest rate, we can use the following to find the effective interest rate
$$r=\left(1+j\right)^{12}-1$$
If you're curious about the annual nominal interest rate, simply multiply the monthly interest rate by $12$. 
$$i=12j=\frac{12}{9}=\frac{4}{3}$$
Which would allow you to use the following
$$r=\left(1+\frac{i}{12}\right)^{12}-1$$
Both approaches eventually show that $r\approx 2.545$, after rounding.
$$r=\left(1+\frac19\right)^{12}-1$$
$$\log_{10}\left(r+1\right)=12\log_{10}\left(\frac{10}{9}\right)$$
$$r=10^{12\left(1-\log_{10}9\right)}-1$$
At this point, the author used 
$$\log_{10}9\approx 0.9542$$
Which leads to the following
$$r\approx 10^{0.5496}-1$$
Surely you can take it from here.

Comment: can you explain how 10 paise treated as interest on 90 paise?

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh I have added an explanation.

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh I have amended this explanation and added more details.

Comment: Can you please show me the calculations then i will accept your answer.

Comment: And in formula r/100. Why not you use divided by 100?

Comment: @JohnAmar, I've updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

You pay $10$ in advance to have $100$, that is you obtain $90$ leaving $10$ as interest; so you have a monthly interest rate of
$$
i_m=\frac{10}{90}=11.11\%
$$
So you have that the yearly interet rate is $i$, given by
$$
(1+i_m)^{12}=1+i\qquad\Longrightarrow\qquad i=(1+i_m)^{12}-1\approx 254.1\%
$$

Comment: Show me the calculations also.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is 213.84%

$(1+0.1)^{12}-1=2.1384$

The formula is $(1+\frac{r}{n})^{n}-1$ where r stands for annual interest rate and n stands for number of compounding periods per year. Since 10% is the monthly rate, $\frac {r}{n}$=0.1, n=12

Comment: here advance payment of interest pay any role?